# JS remove duplicates and characters in Array

Tags: javascript

I would like some assistance to remove duplicates and remove the | and the '' at the start and end.

My code so far

```
const thedates = this.results
            .filter((result) => result.thedate)
            .map((item) => item.thedate)
            .filter((thedate, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(thedate) === i);
          // Split multiple thedates in strings and store in an array
          let thedate = [];
          thedates.forEach((item) => {
            const splitArr = item.split(", ");
            thedate = thedate.concat(splitArr).sort();
          });

          // Filter again for unique thedates
          this.thedates = thedate.filter(
            (thedate, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(thedate) === i
          );
```

My output in the console from the code above

'full-time', 'full-time|full-time', 'full-time|full-time|full-time', 'full-time|full-time|full-time|full-time', 'full-time|full-time|part-time|full-time|part-time|part-time',

I would just like each entry to say: full-time, part-time or full-time if there is just one between the quotes.

Can anyone help to add to my code please?

Comment: Can you provide a sample array with expected output?

Comment: Give sample input

Comment: This is the field in the JSON file which I'm pulling in. 

"thedate": "full-time|part-time|full-time|part-time|full-time|part-time|full-time|part-time|full-time|part-time|full-time|part-time|part-time|full-time|full-time|part-time|full-time|part-time|full-time|full-time|part-time|part-time",

The expected output is

"thedate": "full-time, part-time",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this (similar to @Julien Mellon's post) where you use `.split()`, but you return an array of arrays with the second level array being the entry:

```js
const thedates = ['full-time', 'full-time|part-time', 'full-time|part-time|full-time', 'full-time|full-time|part-time|full-time', 'full-time|full-time|part-time|full-time|part-time|part-time']

const theDatesFormatted = thedates.map(item => {  
  const arr = item.split('|')
  const uniqueArr = [...new Set(arr)]
  return uniqueArr
})

console.log(theDatesFormatted)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply to my question. Your example is great but it doesnt remove the duplicates.

Comment: Hey @user13928344 of course no problem. I updated the code to remove duplicates. The `[...new Set(arr)]` part removes the duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

You're essentially asking two things, how to turn a delimited string into array and how to remove duplicate values from an array. You can parse by using the `.split()` method, and remove duplicates from an array by constructing a set with it then turning it back into an array with the spread operator.

Altogether (where `array` is your input array):

`let filteredArray = [ ...new Set( string.split( '|') ) ]`

```js
const string = "full-time|part-time|full-time|part-time|full-time|part-time|full-time|part-time|full-time|part-time|full-time|part-time|part-time|full-time|full-time|part-time|full-time|part-time|full-time|full-time|part-time|part-time";
let filteredArray = [ ...new Set( string.split( '|') ) ]
let result = filteredArray.join(', ');
console.log(result)
```

Comment: added a demo and completed the answer with a join

Comment: Great, thank you! I will try this within my code too.

Answer (score 0):

if your inputs are

`'full-time', 'full-time|full-time', 'full-time|full-time|full-time', 'full-time|full-time|full-time|full-time', 'full-time|full-time|part-time|full-time|part-time|part-time'`

perhaps you could just call `.split('|')` ?

Comment: Please read the question carefully. And provide a practical code to cover all aspects. If you have any questions or suggestions, first ask them in the comments section.

Comment: I have made some progress but there is still an issue with my output that I dont understand.

Comment: console.log("the result1: " + modecode);
*the result1*: full-time,full-time|full-time,full-time|full-time|full-time,full-time|full-time|full-time time|full-time|part-time|part-time,full-time|full-time| etc etc....

Comment: const string = modecode;
          //"full-time|part-time|full-time|part-time|full-time|part-time|full-time|part-time|full-time|part-time|full-time|part-time|part-time|full-time|full-time|part-time|full-time|part-time|full-time|full-time|part-time|part-time";
          let filteredArray = [...new Set(string.toString().split("|"))];
          let result = filteredArray.join(", ");
          console.log("the result2: " + result);


the result2: full-time,full-time, full-time, part-time, part-time,full-time, full-time,part-time,part-time, full-time,part-time, part-time,part-time

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).